# How to redirect from HandleRequirementAsync in .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I have this code that I need to redirect to /index page. Instead I get an error : `No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication`

```
     protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsAdminRequirement requirement)
                {
                    
            
             context.Fail();
/// how to redirect to index?

         return Task.CompletedTask;
        
        }
```

Comment: `context.Succeed` instead of `context.Fail`? It doesn't looks like you're doing any checks for the policy, also it looks like you need to add `services.AddAuthentication` to the startup file along with the authentication type.

Comment: @AndrewE I just need a redirect, nothing fancy. Any way to achieve this without switching to .NETFramework?

Comment: from the controller you could try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: @AndrewE Please post an answer so that I can accept. Had to add this code:             services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthentication")
                         .AddCookie("CookieAuthentication", config =>
                         {
                             config.LoginPath = "/index";
                             config.ReturnUrlParameter = "signin";
                             config.AccessDeniedPath = "/index";
                         });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add this code for the redirect to work:

```
 services
.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthentication")
.AddCookie("CookieAuthentication", config => 
    { config.LoginPath = "/index";
 config.ReturnUrlParameter = "signin";
 config.AccessDeniedPath = "/index";
 }
    );
```